# OpenLayers: transfer from custom projection to map projection

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, openlayers

I am building a web application with OpenLayers that contains a map that allows insert, edit and remove points, my map is now using “EPSG:4326" projection.

I have shapefiles and xlsx files that contain polygons and points that I need to insert as layer in the map.  The problem is that the shapefiles use EPSG:2309 projection, this is Israel tm grid projection that OpenLayers doesn't recognize.

How do I transfer these points/polygons to the EPSG:4326 projection?

I found this: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2039/html/
But I don't know if its can be helpful, or how...

Comment: I think you can change this in QGIS(Open source desktop GIS software).Please check following link for the details http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/04/tutorial-working-with-projections-in.html

Comment: OpenLayers is supposed to be able to reproject on the fly, but I have not been clever enough to find a tutorial that tells me how. If you find one, please let us know. I just know it should be possible in pure OpenLayers without reprojecting your data with QGis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Openlayer you can specify a specific projection (see the documentation --> http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js)

I found the projection definition in postGIS (EPSG:2309 "Israel / Israeli TM Grid")

You can then use the code below :

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2309"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.73439361111111 +lon_0=35.20451694444445 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-48,55,52,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ";
```

Reprojection will be allowed.